# Karate Stance fighters in MMA

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, ufc

Who are some prevalent UFC/MMA fighters that spar with an actual Karate stance, not just a little bit. Only one I can think of is Stephen Thompson.

[image]

Resources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7U1Ai4H9ao

Comment: Lyoto Machida of course.

Comment: hi @SteveWeigand feel free to place as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guy Mezger did - you can see the bounce and the "rush" that karate points fighters have, he came from a kyokushin background though so not as long a stance as the more shotokan influenced stylists.

Robert Whittaker is another - longer stances the Guy Mezger and you can see that blitz/rush style a bit.

Machida's the obvious one, he's also the main shotokan stylist who competed, the others tend to come from other styles.

Kyoji Horiguchi is a less well known one - 3 years in the UFC, now a bellator fighter, also a shotokan stylist.

Gunnar Nelson's another Goju guy, with a noticeable karate influence in his stances. I think it's his main striking background combined with BJJ.

If you look at Japanese fighters, especially at the lighter weights, there's an unsurprising number of karate guys.